# Django: writing a view to delete an item with checkboxes

Tags: python, html, django, checkbox, django-forms

I need help writing a view that gets the POST data which then finds out which checkboxes have been checked, and then deletes the items from the database matched by id.
Originally, This was a checkbox problem. In a edit order form, there are a list of items. Now I CAN remove the item using a bit of javascript but it does not get save because I need to remove it completly from my database. I tried using my edit order views to remove an item using the delete(), but that doe not work. There must be something else I am doing wrong but I don't know what.

```
delete_item = request.POST.get('delete_item', None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.OrderForm(request.POST, instance = order)
        if form.is_valid() and save_item is not None:
            form.save(True)
            request.user.message_set.create(message = "The order has been updated successfully.")
            return HttpResponse("<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">window.opener.location = window.opener.location; window.close();</script>")

        if status is not None and contact is not None and save_status is not None and delete_item is not None:
            try:
                for id in status_items:
                    item = models.StorageItem.objects.get(pk = id)
                    delete = item
                    delete.delete()
                    current_status = models.ItemStatusHistory(item = item, contact = contact, status = status,
                                                    user = request.user)
                    current_status.save()
            except:
                pass
            request.user.message_set.create(message = "Status successfully changed for {0} items".format(len(status_items)))

{% for item in items %}
        <tr class="items_table_row">
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="item" value="{{item.pk}}" checked="checked"{% endif %}>
                <td>{{item.tiptop_id}}</td><td>{{item.alternative_id}}</td><td>{{item.title}}</td><td>{{item.type}}</td><td>{{item.format}}</td>
                <td><span id="{{item.pk}}" name="type">{{item.itemstatushistory_set.latest}}</span></td><td>{{item.itemstatushistory_set.latest.date.date|date:"d M Y"}}</td>
                <td><a href="{% url tiptop.views.edit_item item.client.pk item.pk %}" onclick="return showAddAnotherPopup(this);">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5):

Given your template using checkboxes with `name="item"`... .delete() should work.

```
Items.objects.filter(id__in=request.POST.getlist('items')).delete()
```

Are you getting an exception? Is the `delete()` code ever running? Throw in a print statement.

You have "a ton of code", a lot of conditions we're not familiar with, and a try/except block so I just want to make sure the view is actually making it to the delete stage.

**UPDATE:** this is a rough piece of code to follow as a stranger to your code.
`if status is not None and contact is not None and save_status is not None and delete_item is not None:`

Why don't you just check for the existence of a specific button pressed instead?

```
# html
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save Items" />
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete Items" />

# view
if request.POST.get('delete'):
   Items.objects.filter(id__in=request.POST.getlist('items')).delete()
elif request.POST.get('save'):
   form = Form(request.POST)
# ... so on
```

Comment: well any time I throw a print statement after the delete() stage, it does not even want to print. I assume the same as you. I does not want to go to the delete stage at all.

Comment: yeah, that's your problem then. `if status is not None and contact is not None and save_status is not None and delete_item is not None:` is  a hard line to follow. Why don't i suggest a simpler approach.. updating

Comment: This makes more sense but this still does not work. May have to do with this line  Items.objects.filter(id__in=request.POST.getlist('items')).delete(). Actually items is defined in my views as items = models.StorageItem.objects.filter(orderstoragelist__order__pk = order.pk) But even if I replace StorageItem over Items it still fails to delete.

Comment: Yeah, that fat `if foo1, foo2, not foo3, foo4 == foo5` looking line can be replaced with: "which button was pressed?" :)