# How to delete records in Django from an HTML table with Checkboxes?

Tags: checkbox, django-forms, django-views

So I have a table that lists all the record from my model.

But now I'm trying to make a `Checkbox` and delete it (kinda like the `Django` admin way), I can't find the documentation for this , as I'm sure there are several ways to to this.

But I'm trying to figure out like whats the proper way for doing this , should I do this via form ? or `Modelform` ? or `AJAX`?

Would appreciate if someone could have an example.

Comment: Having similar problem. I have a table. Each row has edit and delete buttons, but also Google mail like check boxes, including check all function. I'm looking for an ajax solution, but this can be accomplished with Django forms as well.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting multiple records with Django forms and views has been answered elsewhere:

[Django: writing a view to delete an item with checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897291/django-writing-a-view-to-delete-an-item-with-checkboxes)

Essentially, you get the list of items (checked boxes) in the POST arrary and delete them:

```
Items.objects.filter(id__in=request.POST.getlist('items')).delete()
```

But as I said in my comment, an AJAX solution would be nice, so this answer might not be as good if you are looking for that...