# Deleting an item from a list using a checkbox in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a file upload that allows the user to upload a file to the server and then they are displayed on a page in a list view.
Now I am trying to delete a file from the list using a checkbox and a delete button but I can't seem to get it to work.
I know there is an answer here on the same topic but it's not what I'm looking for. [Django: writing a view to delete an item with checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897291/django-writing-a-view-to-delete-an-item-with-checkboxes)

here is the code that I have so far:

st.html

```
<!-- List of uploaded documents -->
{% if documents %}
    <ul>
    {% for document in documents %}
        <li><a href="{{ document.docfile.url }}">{{ document.docfile.name }} <input type="checkbox" name="doc"></a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Delete file" name="delete"></p>
    <button><a href="{% url 'login.views.uploadpage' %}">Upload a File!</a></button>
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No documents.</p>
{% endif %}
```

views.py

```
def stat1(request):
    if request.POST.get('delete'):
        Document.objects.filter(id_in=request.POST.getlist('doc')).delete()
```

I tried putting in a print() to see if the code after in the if in the views.py was executing and it's not.
I'm only new to python and Django so any help would be nice!

Comment: You're not POSTing anything - there's no method set, no form, no action/endpoint urls. Is there extra relevant code that's not included in the question? I'd recommend having a look at formsets. I've used them extensively for situations like this. Formset docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/