# Creating a delete button for each record

Tags: python, django, post

I have a website which I have a bunch of records in the database. There are two fields, `Name` and `Comment`. `models.py`:

```
class Db_test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "db_test"
```

I have a page where all the records are displayed with a delete button next to it. My current page:

[image: Records with delete buttons]

I have the following `views.py` (just the relevant function):

```
def delete(request):
    objects = Db_test.objects.all()
    items = []

    if request.method == "POST":
        print(int(list(request.POST)[-1]))
        objects[int(list(request.POST)[-1])].delete()

    for obj in objects:
        items.append([obj.name, obj.comment])

    return render(request, "models_test/delete.html", {"values": items})
```

The relevant DTL section:

```
{% for i in values %}
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>{{ forloop.counter }}: {{ i.0 }}<input type="submit" name={{forloop.counter0}} value="X"></p>
        <p>{{ i.1 }}</p>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

All this works fine except that it occasionally raises an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mooncheesez/Desktop/django_projects/test_project/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/mooncheesez/Desktop/django_projects/test_project/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/mooncheesez/Desktop/django_projects/test_project/venv/testproject/models_test/views.py", line 32, in delete
    print(int(list(request.POST)[-1]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'
```

This line is the culprit:

```
objects[int(list(request.POST)[-1])].delete()
```

For some odd reason, `request.POST` only contains the `csrf_token` but not the submitted button. Note that it only happens occasionally too.

I searched around stackoverflow and I only found this post for deleting with checkboxes: [Django: writing a view to delete an item with checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897291/django-writing-a-view-to-delete-an-item-with-checkboxes)

What do I do to avoid this? Are there better alternatives for what I am doing?

Comment: What are you trying to do here: `int(list(request.POST)[-1])`? `request.POST` is a dictionary of key/value pairs. It doesn't make sense to try to convert it to a list. It also doesn't make sense to try and delete objects based on their order in the database - you need to use their database ID instead.

Comment: @solarissmoke I see. That explains the occasional error. Is there a better way to do it? If so, please post it as an answer! (I would imagine indexing something like `[x for x in request.POST if x != 'csrfmiddlewaretoken']`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach altogether.

In your view, pass the object itself:

```
objects = Db_test.objects.all()
return render(request, "models_test/delete.html", {"values": objects})
```

In your template:

```
{% for obj in object %}
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>{{ forloop.counter }}: {{ obj.name }}<input type="submit" name="delete_items" value="{{ obj.pk }}"></p>
        <p>{{ obj.comment }}</p>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

In your view again:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    # Fetch list of items to delete, by ID
    items_to_delete = request.POST.getlist('delete_items')
    # Delete those items all in one go
    Db_test.objects.filter(pk__in=items_to_delete).delete()
```

A few general comments:

- There is nothing to be gained by passing a list like `[obj.name, obj.comment]` to your template. Just pass the object itself. This will be much easier to maintain.
- Making changes based on natural database order is definitely not the right approach here - in fact it is dangerous and error-prone (e.g, what if items were added to the database while you were rendering the form?). Your database objects have a unique ID to identify them - use that.
- `request.POST` is a dictionary. Converting it to a list doesn't make sense. If you supply a list of inputs all with the same name, you can use [`getlist()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) to fetch them.

Comment: The code works well. However, is there another way to keep the `value='X'`?

Comment: Not with an `<input>` tag. You could use a `button` instead: `<button type="submit" name="delete_items" value="{{ obj.pk }}">X</button>`