# Checked rows are not being deleted from HTML table/ Database (Django)

Tags: python, html, django

I created an html table in a django template

```
<form action="/delete_team/" method="POST" >
  {% csrf_token %}                     
  <input type="submit" name = "delete" class="btn btn-danger float-right" value="Delete">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" name="checkAll"></th>
        <th>Team ID</th>
        <th>Male</th>
        <th>Female</th>
        <th>Officer</th>
        <th>Deadline</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for team in teams %}
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checked" class="case"></td>
        <td>{{ team.team_id}}</td>
        <td>{{ team.male }}</td>
        <td>{{ team.female }}</td>
        <td>{{ team.officer }}</td>
        <td>{{ team.date }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>    
</form>
```

here is the code that i wrote in my **views.py**:

```
def delete_team(request):    
    if request.method == "POST":
        pkm = request.POST.getlist("checked") 
        selected_objects = mtch_tbl.objects.filter(team_id__in=pkm)
        selected_objects.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/main/")
```

now when i check a row and click delete nothing happens...i only get returned to my page again with the same data. Kindly point out my mistake, i can't figure out how to write the views

Here are my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from teamplanner import views

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("delete_team/",views.delete_team),
]
```

Is it possible for the jQuery code to be interfering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418713/creating-a-delete-button-for-each-record) S.O solution, it's not related to checkboxes but the idea is pretty much the same. All I did was edit my checkbox input tag a little and added values to it:

```
<tbody>
  {% for team in teams %}
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checked" class="case" value="{{ team.team_id }}"></td>
    <td>{{ team.team_id}}</td>
    <td>{{ team.male }}</td>
    <td>{{ team.female }}</td>
    <td>{{ team.officer }}</td>
    <td>{{ team.date }}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

that's all there was to it, no need to change the views or the url path.

Still I really appreciate the help, Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Your views have many codes that to me aren't necessary, if you're planning on deleting a team, it's just Normal that you've FIRST registered a team. So here's what you should do..

```
def delete_team(request,delete_id):    
    delete = mtch_tbl.objects.get(id=delete_id)
    #to make it more interesting, you should add a view to your models (i,'ll display the model below)
    delete.view=True
    delete.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/main/")
```

Add this to your models
    Class modelname (models.Model):
        view=models.BooleanField(default=False)

In your URLs here's what you should do:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path("delete_team/(?<delete_id>\d+)/$",views.delete_team),
    ]''''
```

I hope this helps

Comment: i did as you said, now i get **TypeError at /delete_team/ delete_team() missing 1 required positional argument: 'delete_id'**, team_id is my primary key here so I tried replacing "id = delete_id" to "team_id = delete_id", but didn't work

Comment: but I don't want to delete a single team at a time, I want multiple teams that I've checked in the table to be deleted

Comment: I've added my urls.py

Comment: you see my team_id is actually not an int, it's characters, e.g. team_id = 'NGMT123','NGMT124' etc

Comment: I tried that url but got **Page not Found http://127.0.0.1:8000/delete_team/**, then i gave a name **"delete_team"** to the url path and in my form action i wrote **"{% url 'delete_team' %}"**, then i got **"NoReverseMatch at /main/ Reverse for 'delete_team' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['delete_team/\\(\\?(?P<delete_id>[^/]+)\\\\d\\+\\)/$']
"**

Answer (score 0):

I think you're storing it in a variable. Try this:

```
def delete_team(request):    
    if request.method == "POST":
        pkm = request.POST.getlist("check") 
        mtch_tbl.objects.filter(team_id__in=pkm).delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/main/")
```

Comment: i think there is something wrong I've written in the html code, is it supposed to be that way, that i've written? somwhow it's not grabbing the checked rows...