# How to perform .delete() queryset in Django in a ListView?

Tags: javascript, django, datatables, django-class-based-views

Here is what I've done so far:

1.) I've made a javascript function that gets all the id's of the items (using checkbox select) in the database like so (this is DataTables):

```
function () {
    // count check used for checking selected items.
    var count = table.rows( { selected: true } ).count();

    // Count check.
    // Count must be greater than 0 to delete an item.
    // if count <= 0, delete functionality won't continue.
    if (count > 0) {
        var data = table.rows( { selected: true } ).data();

        var list = []; 

        for (var i=0; i < data.length ;i++){
           // alert(data[i][2]);
           list.push(data[i][2]);
        }

        var sData = list.join();

        // alert(sData)
        document.getElementById('delete_items_list').value = sData;
        }
}
```

It outputs something like `1,2,5,7` depending on what rows I have selected.

2.) Passed the values inside a `<input type="hidden">`.

Now, I've read a [post that says you can delete data in Django database using a checkbox,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4898070/7209628) but I'm not sure how exactly can I use this.

I'm guessing I should put it in the ListView that I made, but how can I do that when I click the "Delete selected items" button, I can follow [this answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4898070/7209628)

I'm trying to achieve what Django Admin looks like when you delete items.

My ListView looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use linked example. Django Admin do it the same way, You send selected ids and django do filtering by given values and after django apply selected action for selected items.

**UPDATE**

For example.

```
class List(ListView);
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ids = self.request.POST.get('ids', "")
        # ids if string like "1,2,3,4"
        ids = ids.split(",")
        try:
            # Check ids are valid numbers
            ids = map(int, ids)
        except ValueError as e:
            return JsonResponse(status=400)
        # delete items
        self.model.objects.filter(id__in=ids).delete()
        return JsonResponse({"status": "ok"}, status=204)
```

And html:

```
<button id="delete-button">Del</button>
<div id="items-table">
      {% for object in objects_list %}
           <div class="item" data-id="{{object.id}}">{{ object.name }}</div>
      {% endfor %}
</div>
<script>
     $(function(){
         $('#delete-button').on('click', function(e) {
             // Get selected items. You should update it according to your template structure.
             var ids = $.map($('#items-table item'), function(item) {
                   return $(item).data('id')
             }).join(',');
             $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: window.location.href ,
                 data: {'ids': ids},
                 success: function (res) {
                     // Update page
                     window.location.href = window.location.href;
                 },
                 error: function () {
                  // Display message or something else
                 }
             });
         })
     })();
</script>
```

Comment: How exactly should I do it? Can you teach me a step-by-step example? I'm using a class-based ListView and a DataTables button function as shown above.

Comment: @Kenny Look at updated answer. I've attached simple example.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is big help. As of now I'm editing your code according to the structure of mine. Hoping I could get it to work. Wait a sec.. Thank you once again!